# Migrating wordpress from local server to host

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I just made a Wordpress website on a local server (easyPHP) and it works great. Now it is time to move it to my host server, but I am facing a problem. After migrating the website, I noted that all special characters are replaced by a "?". And in the admin dashboard, when I check my pages, all pages title that are supposed to contain special characters are empty (Only the title) and some of their custom fields does not exist anymore. One more thing, I use the "Custom Post Type UI" plugin, and all posts created with it are not displayed.

Now, for the steps I made to migrate are :

1. Export local database from phpmyadmin, in UTF-8 format (I let all the default settings).
2. Upload my local website files to the server (the wordpress folder itself).
3. Import my local database to the server by phpmyadmin
4. Change the "option_value" field from "siteurl" and "home" rows from the "wp_options" table to my server url.
5. Changed the database access from the "wp-config.php" file
6. Gone to the wp-admin panel in general tab and clicked "save", same thing for permalink tab.

After that, I exported my new database to check if it contained any instance of my local URL and it did not.

I have now no idea why I get this problem. I think this is an encoding problem but don't know nothing more. Any one could help me?

For information, there are my local and host setup :

Local

- Wordpress 4.2.4
- PHP 5.5.8
- MYSQL 5.6.15
- Database collation : utf8mb4_unicode_ci
- Table storage engine : MyISAM
- Table collation : utf8mb4_unicode_ci
- Row collation : utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Host server

- PHP 5.4.24
- MYSQL 5.5.42-37.1-log
- Database collation : utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Answer (score 0):

Try updating PHP 5.4 to 5.5 on your server
Also, you haven't mnetioned if Wordpress is installed on your server

Comment: I am not sure I am able to do that, because it is not my own server, it is a web hosting (JustHost). Correct me if I am wrong, but they have control on that, but not me.

Comment: And also, if I did not mentioned Wordpress on the server, it is because I upload all my Wordpress local files on it, so I don't have to install it, as I already configured Wordpress and moved it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with your encoding check the website http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html to learn more about encoding

Comment: I read it, and tried to change the header charset by the index.php file and it changed nothing. I begin to believe that it is my webhost server that is not UTF-8. But I don't know exactly where to change that, as I did it by the index.php file

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try any wordpress plugin to migrate your website without hassle.

I would recommend that, it would take hardly any efforts to migrate.

> https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Give it a try its very easy and takes very little input from you.