# Migrate WordPress from local docker to hosting provider

Tags: php, wordpress, docker

Currently, I'm creating a WordPress (WP) site on a local docker container. I would like to eventually migrate it to my live GoDaddy website that has my old WP site running on it.

What is the easiest way to migrate my local docker WordPress instance to my live GoDaddy site?

I was thinking it would be easiest to export the docker site with the All-in-One WP Migration plugin and then import it into the GoDaddy site using the same plugin. I would just need to update the database credentials in the wp-config.php file.

Has anyone made this move before? If so, am I'm missing anything?

I see there is a similar post here: [Migrating wordpress from local server to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955612/migrating-wordpress-from-local-server-to-host)

However, I was thinking I could use the migration plugin to do most of the heavy lifting.

Thanks,
M

Answer (score 0):

Sync tools can be used to transfer your new files from your local system to your website. You must create a docker **volume** before using Sync tools.